# Raspberry Pi 16x2 LCD Screen Glitches After a Few Seconds

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, zero, lcd

I have a 16x2 LCD Screen that displays the time and date live. The problem is, it starts automatically on boot, but glitches out when it does.

[What happens when it starts on boot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ADAfg.jpg)

In rc.local, I have added a line that says (sleep 10; python /home/pi/Document/LCD.py)
Which will start it on boot. I think it might be starting too early in the process. Something that also makes me believe that is that when I plug the display cable in, it has a better rate of success. Maybe it delays the process enough for the GPIO pins to initialize? I have tried to add it as a system service but it doesn't seem to work.

My code:

```
# The wiring for the LCD is as follows:
# 1 : GND
# 2 : 5V
# 3 : Contrast (0-5V)*
# 4 : RS (Register Select)
# 5 : R/W (Read Write)       - GROUND THIS PIN
# 6 : Enable or Strobe
# 7 : Data Bit 0             - NOT USED
# 8 : Data Bit 1             - NOT USED
# 9 : Data Bit 2             - NOT USED
# 10: Data Bit 3             - NOT USED
# 11: Data Bit 4
# 12: Data Bit 5
# 13: Data Bit 6
# 14: Data Bit 7
# 15: LCD Backlight +5V**
# 16: LCD Backlight GND

#import
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

# Define GPIO to LCD mapping
LCD_RS = 7
LCD_E  = 8
LCD_D4 = 25
LCD_D5 = 24
LCD_D6 = 23
LCD_D7 = 18


# Define some device constants
LCD_WIDTH = 16    # Maximum characters per line
LCD_CHR = True
LCD_CMD = False

LCD_LINE_1 = 0x80 # LCD RAM address for the 1st line
LCD_LINE_2 = 0xC0 # LCD RAM address for the 2nd line

# Timing constants
E_PULSE = 0.0005
E_DELAY = 0.0005

def main():
  # Main program block

  GPIO.setwarnings(False)
  GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)       # Use BCM GPIO numbers
  GPIO.setup(LCD_E, GPIO.OUT)  # E
  GPIO.setup(LCD_RS, GPIO.OUT) # RS
  GPIO.setup(LCD_D4, GPIO.OUT) # DB4
  GPIO.setup(LCD_D5, GPIO.OUT) # DB5
  GPIO.setup(LCD_D6, GPIO.OUT) # DB6
  GPIO.setup(LCD_D7, GPIO.OUT) # DB7


  # Initialise display
  lcd_init()
  while True:
    e = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
    date = time.strftime("%Y:%m:%d") 

    # Send some test
    lcd_string(date,LCD_LINE_1) #Change 'text' to what you want.
    lcd_string(e,LCD_LINE_2)

def lcd_init():
  # Initialise display
  lcd_byte(0x33,LCD_CMD) # 110011 Initialise
  lcd_byte(0x32,LCD_CMD) # 110010 Initialise
  lcd_byte(0x06,LCD_CMD) # 000110 Cursor move direction
  lcd_byte(0x0C,LCD_CMD) # 001100 Display On,Cursor Off, Blink Off
  lcd_byte(0x28,LCD_CMD) # 101000 Data length, number of lines, font size
  lcd_byte(0x01,LCD_CMD) # 000001 Clear display
  time.sleep(E_DELAY)

def lcd_byte(bits, mode):
  # Send byte to data pins
  # bits = data
  # mode = True  for character
  #        False for command

  GPIO.output(LCD_RS, mode) # RS

  # High bits
  GPIO.output(LCD_D4, False)
  GPIO.output(LCD_D5, False)
  GPIO.output(LCD_D6, False)
  GPIO.output(LCD_D7, False)
  if bits&0x10==0x10:
    GPIO.output(LCD_D4, True)
  if bits&0x20==0x20:
    GPIO.output(LCD_D5, True)
  if bits&0x40==0x40:
    GPIO.output(LCD_D6, True)
  if bits&0x80==0x80:
    GPIO.output(LCD_D7, True)

  # Toggle 'Enable' pin
  lcd_toggle_enable()

  # Low bits
  GPIO.output(LCD_D4, False)
  GPIO.output(LCD_D5, False)
  GPIO.output(LCD_D6, False)
  GPIO.output(LCD_D7, False)
  if bits&0x01==0x01:
    GPIO.output(LCD_D4, True)
  if bits&0x02==0x02:
    GPIO.output(LCD_D5, True)
  if bits&0x04==0x04:
    GPIO.output(LCD_D6, True)
  if bits&0x08==0x08:
    GPIO.output(LCD_D7, True)

  # Toggle 'Enable' pin
  lcd_toggle_enable()

def lcd_toggle_enable():
  # Toggle enable
  time.sleep(E_DELAY)
  GPIO.output(LCD_E, True)
  time.sleep(E_PULSE)
  GPIO.output(LCD_E, False)
  time.sleep(E_DELAY)

def lcd_string(message,line):
  # Send string to display




  message = message.ljust(LCD_WIDTH," ")

  lcd_byte(line, LCD_CMD)

  for i in range(LCD_WIDTH):
    lcd_byte(ord(message[i]),LCD_CHR)

if __name__ == '__main__':

  try:
    main()
  except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
  finally:
    lcd_byte(0x01, LCD_CMD)
    lcd_string("Goodbye!",LCD_LINE_1)
    GPIO.cleanup()
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I see three problems.

1. Most HD44780 displays (like this display) require 5V I/O. The Raspberry Pi uses 3.3V I/O, which may not be sufficient for some displays.
2. Relatedly: if the display *ever* gets put into read mode, it may attempt to drive 5V onto the data bus. This will damage the I/O pins on the Pi.
3. `GPIO.cleanup()` resets any output pins on the Pi to inputs. This will leave inputs on the display floating, which will cause unexpected behavior.

Potential solutions:

1. Use a display which supports 3.3V I/O natively, or which has a level translator or protocol converter built in. (I2C "backpacks" for these displays are a common solution; they'll also save you a couple of pins.)
2. Add a level translator between the Pi and the display, and pull the E pin low with a resistor so that it cannot float high while undriven by the Pi.

Comment: I am using a Raspberry Pi Zero, and using the 5 volt pin, would that mean it would be getting 5v or not?

Comment: That only provides 5V to VCC. The other inputs still have a logical high of 3.3V or less.

Comment: Sorry I've been inactive, level translator took a while to come - slow international shipping. I've hooked them up, they are working fine (tested with a voltmeter) pulled the e pin low with a 560 ohm resistor, and got rid of gpio.cleanup(). But, when I boot it, the backlight comes on, but doesn't display any text?